# Ad mob small size ad

Tags: android, admob

Is that possible to load ad in 150 * 150 dp box?

I read somewhere that we can load ad only with size between the specified range.

For native ads, small (Width: 280dp-1200dp, Height: 80dp-612dp), medium (Width: 280dp-1200dp, Height: 132dp-1200dp), Large (Width: 280dp-1200dp, Height: 250dp-1200dp).

For Banner, smaller size is 320x50.

So I want to know that- is that any possible way to load ad into 150dp * 150dp box?

Comment: it will show partial advertisement if you will put in fix size box

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not. AdMob just doesn't traffic in that particular size. I'd recommend looking into another format, such as interstitials, to see if that could also fit your app's design.